# Silencing Rails schema load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've written a [multi-tenancy gem](https://github.com/bradrobertson/apartment) for Rails.

When I create a new tenant, I load in the schema.rb file.  This works fine, except that each time I do it, I get a deluge of log messages:

```
-- create_table("users", {:force=>true})
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "users_id_seq" for serial column "users.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "users_pkey" for table "users"
   -> 0.0102s
-- add_index("users", ["email"], {:name=>"index_users_on_email", :unique=>true})
   -> 0.0035s
-- add_index("users", ["reset_password_token"], {:name=>"index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique=>true})
   -> 0.0040s
```

Etc etc...  all typical of the loading the `schema.rb` file.  My problem is that it's rather annoying to see this during tests.  I really don't care to see this and it muddies up my test output, making it much harder for me to debug and verify tests etc...

Does anyone know of a way I can silence this output?  I've tried the following in my gem:

```
Rails.logger.silence{ load("#{Rails.root}/db/seeds.rb") }
```

but that doesn't change a thing.  Does anyone know of a config option or some other way I can silence the output from schema loading?

Comment: Here I posted a solution that works with spork:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425490/silence-rails-schema-load-for-spork/7633608#7633608

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can silence the schema load output when using spork as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425490/silence-rails-schema-load-for-spork/7633608#7633608).

Answer (score 4):

After some digging, here's what I've learned.

You can silence the log by doing the following:

```
silence_stream(STDOUT) do
  load "#{Rails.root}/db/schema.rb"
end
```

[silence_stream](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Kernel.html#method-i-silence_stream) is a Kernel method, so you should be able to call it and it will kill STDOUT which is where output is being logged to. So the above worked for me.

**If you are using Spork, this will not work**

So for Spork, you typically load the schema.rb in memory for each run. Unfortunately, Spork gets the output, even before the silence_stream wrapper, and pushes the output through. I discovered this whilst reading [a Ruby Inside article](http://www.rubyinside.com/careful-cutting-to-get-faster-rspec-runs-with-rails-5207.html) which explains this. The article is confusing because he left the code in there, despite it doing nothing for Spork.

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks so much!  Now if I could just figure out how to silence all of those extra noticies from postgresql I'd be happy.  silent-postgres doesn't seem to get them all.

Comment: Hey, sorry BlueFish, in the end, Nils' answer was *exactly* what I was looking for and works with Spork as well so I've got to reward him!  Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Hey Brad. No worries... it worked for me too so I have no hard feelings. I was starting to hate the schema logging when using spork.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me in Rails 5 (which has deprecated `silence_stream`). In this example, I'm loading the schema in a specified time so that I can predict the output, and I set `ActiveRecord::Schema.verbose` to `false`:

```
  setup do
    # Normalize time in order to match fixture file
    travel_to Time.zone.parse('2015-03-01T12:00:00') do
      ActiveRecord::Schema.verbose = false
      Rake::Task['db:schema:load'].reenable
      Rake::Task['db:schema:load'].invoke
      Rake::Task['db:fixtures:load'].reenable
      Rake::Task['db:fixtures:load'].invoke
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that adding this line min_messages to the `database.yml` quieted things down nicely:

```
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_test
  template: template0
  pool: 5
  username: <%= ENV['USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['PASSWORD'] %>
  min_messages: WARNING
```

I also found the template parameter solves the SQL_ASCII encoding problem on Ubuntu
    `PG::Error: ERROR:  new encoding (UTF8) is incompatible with the encoding of the template database (SQL_ASCII)`

Answer (score 1):

It's actually `ActiveRecord::Migration` producing the log output, so for what it's worth the most correct solution would be:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.suppress_messages do
  load("schema.rb")
end
```

See [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html#method-i-suppress_messages). (See also the "Controlling verbosity" section.)